# How to move a button to center in salesforce lightning component

Tags: salesforce-lightning

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >


       <H1> <ui:button label="Web to Lead Form"  press="{!c.openActionWindow}"/> </H1>
```

Css

```
.THIS {
}

H1.THIS {

    font-family: 'calibri';
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: White;
    border: 5px solid white;
    padding: 20px 110px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Here is the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9qoO.jpg), where i am not able to move the inside button to center

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to flex the host component if that's an option?

```
.THIS {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```